# What is boxstub_sql.exe file in sql server2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

What is the use of **boxstub_sql** in sql server.I am trying to the gather the information but i didn't get why it is Actually Used For.
   "Accorindng to my Reserach it is Some Kind of **VirusTool.**IS it a Virustool Please Let Me know

Comment: Iam Not **Suspecting** The that it will create abnormal Behavour.just i Want to know what its Use.And When iam Browsing in some blogs i got to know its a Virus Tool which stop abrnormal things happing in the sql Server.And its Ust My **Curiosity** to learn new things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Boxstub_sql.exe` is a type of `EXE` file associated with MSDN disc 5003.03 developed by Microsoft for the Windows Operating System. The latest known version of `Boxstub_sql.exe` is `1.0.0.0`, which was produced for Windows.

Previous Microsoft SQL Express files supplied from Microsoft were built from the `"SFXCAB.EXE"` where as Microsoft SQL Express 2014 is built from `"boxstub_sql.exe"`.

Comment: But what did this .exe file will do

Comment: @UnishBasha It will build Microsoft SQL Express files

Answer (score 0):

`Boxstub_sql.exe` unwraps `.box` SQL Server archive file to a folder. A web installer will download `Boxstub_sql.exe` and associated `.box` file and use `Boxstub_sql.exe` to extract the installer.